# How to install mysql 5.1. if I already have 5.5. installed?

Tags: mysql

Currently I have mysql 5.5 installed localy.

How can I install and use mysql 5.1 server?

I also need to be able to go back to 5.5. at one point.

Comment: Are you sure you want that? A 5.5 database will NOT be compatible with 5.1 so you will need to restart from scratch and manually fix you data dump... I would fix the problem that prevents you from using 5.5 ;)

Answer (score 2):

It will not downgrade with 5.5 config files.

`apt-get purge mysql* -y`

`find / |grep -i mysql`

And backup and remove all folders, then install mysql 5.1.

As for upgrading to 5.5, use `apt-get upgrade`.

Don't forget to DUMP all your databases (mysqldump or phpmyadmin)!